# Spoiler text doesn't work with numbered lists - Intended behavior? Workaround?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown-rendering, spoilers, list

The spoiler markdown is sometimes *cough* messed up. Today's edition: **Spoiler doesn't work with numbered lists**.

```
>! 1. Foo
   2. Bar
   3. Baz
```

renders like

> ! 1. Foo
>      2. Bar
>      3. Baz

I could instead do

```
>! 1. Foo
>! 2. Bar
>! 3. Baz
```

but that also turns into

> 1. Foo
>  2. Bar
>  3. Baz

Sheesh, it's ugly! I could also insert two spaces in the second version and get "bar" and "baz" in new lines, but that's still not proper or enough indentation.

Can this be fixed please? Are there any good and un-ugly workarounds? (preferably using markdown)

Comment: To expand on this, they don't currently parse *any* other block elements inside them. This includes headers, blockquotes, code blocks, and horizontal rules in addition to the lists.

Comment: Also please consider the possibility that [you're hiding too much](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/1508/4204).

Comment: And sometimes mathjax breaks too if i recall correctly.

Comment: @Josh we need it to hide a chemistry homework answer; recommended formatting is spoiler, but it's not necessary.

Comment: Awww, maaan…I was four paragraphs into a lengthy question about this very matter.

Comment: @JoshCaswell What if the post is [just one long list of answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/22383/14221), with brief explanations for each answer on the same line?

Comment: Why are you hiding _the text from the question_, @BlacklightShining?!

Comment: @JoshCaswell …I didn't think of that. Now that you mention it, though, I can't figure out how to spoiler just the answer on each line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spoilers don't work at the Markdown level. You cannot use any block-level Markdown constructs with it.

How it works is that there's a postprocessor that looks for `<blockquote>` tags where each line starts with `!`. Such `<blockquote>`s get a `spoiler` class added. That's it.

And because of the `!`-at-start-of-each-line check, you cannot possibly have other block-level Markdown constructs within, such as code blocks, lists, etc. You can use manual HTML, though:

> 1. Test item 1
> 2. Test item 2

Answer (score 3):

Well, unless the list itself is spoiler, you can hide each item on its own:

```
1. >!Foo
1. >!Bar
1. >!Baz
```

Which turns into:

1. > Foo
2. > Bar
3. > Baz

Comment: Oh yes, [I thought of this too](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3229?m=24160022#24160022), but it's not quite the same thing I'm looking for.